# TestFlight didn't show last build

Tags: testflight

since upload last three build tester didn't get any update in testflight for testing a build i found many solution in stack overflow but none of the solution helped me out.

my appstore build:

[image]

i **found** **solution** from **here** ...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171888/5362750

Thanks all of you for support

Comment: is the build uploaded successfully?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Yes also i validate the build then i upload

Comment: Check email linked with apple account, you might have received email listing with issues apple found on your build which most of the times related to .plist file for any missing permission description. After removing issues do change the build Number as you cannot upload with the same build number as previous one.

Comment: @Piyush ok we will check for that but i think this is not an issue as i not change anything from last build which is effect on my .plist file

Comment: @Piyush this is not an issue can you help me out more i this if you know

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya hace you checked your email ?? It happened with me before too and the solution was in mail,,, Check it once

Comment: @KeshuR. i checked mail there is no mail from the apple

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya can you please cross check the linked email with your account there must be mail regarding build rejection. This happened with me recently and I got the mail from them with rejection reason.

Comment: Please check your apple account mail may you received reasons.

Comment: Many are facing the same issue since 9th feb 2020
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/128878?start=45&tstart=0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not Showing update for internal testers in testflight for new build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162448/not-showing-update-for-internal-testers-in-testflight-for-new-build)

Comment: @DanielStorm yes

Answer (score 0):

Check in the "Activity Tab" where you can check the current activity of each build and if it was failed it would mention there , Also make sure that the appstore URL , Scheme Name were not changed during the time

Comment: all the build uploaded successfully there