# Not Showing update for internal testers in testflight for new build

Tags: ios, swift, testflight

I have uploaded the new build yesterday , after accepting missing compliance option status of build is 'Testing' but  still invitation is not send to internal testers  and not even showing any update in testflight app  for that build . I have added 4 testers for this build . Please refer screenshot for the same .[image]

Comment: I have the same problem since yesterday, I sent 4 or 5 builds thinking something was wrong with them. No invites are sent but the build says it's in testing.

Comment: Yes @alex , please let me know if you figure out some solution for it

Comment: it seems the problem solved itself, but I had to send yet another build.

Comment: I have the same problem since yesterday (Monday 10th) and no success even after another build. Any luck?

Comment: @Jorge , Adding 'App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption' in info.plist file is the work around

Answer (score 13):

I got this from https://twitter.com/hashtag/testflight

> We can fix TestFlightApp new build issue by adding  the "App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption" key in Info.plist (in my case set NO)and republishing
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations

Source: https://twitter.com/Reddybashashaik/status/1227231610434490368

Add ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption to your Info.plist

---

I also noted that it seems like it works to invite users by

- being in App Store Connect,
- clicking on your app,
- choose *TestFlight* from the menu,
- then click on your latest build number (possibly folding it out from under *Version X.X.X*),
- and then invite users manually under the headline *Individual Tester*.

Comment: Elimaa  Thanks a lot , this fixed  issue .  Adding 'App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption' in info.plist file was the work around .

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue you have to add new key *ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption* into your info.plist.

See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/128878?start=105 for details.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all account from testing mail address who's not getting an update and add again they will get a new invite again. 
They have to accept the request and they need to use the Testflight app in that they will enter a code which they will get in the mail.

Comment: I have removed the tester and added them back , they received the invite mail but after redeeming the invite code in testflight app it still shows the old version of the  app .

Comment: Something is wrong from your console side. Try with the new build, it can help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841117/missing-compliance-in-status-when-i-add-built-for-internal-testing-in-test-fligh 

try with this.

Comment: I tried this as well but the invite is not for the latest test version of the app. In our case we got the invitation for a version of last week and not the version we uploaded today.

Comment: Yes @jHogen , for us also after redeeming the code in testflight , its shows old version of the app . So i think we also received the invite for the older version for that app. So did you receive any updated for the latest version  afterwards ? How did you solve this issue ?

Comment: @Vivek I have not yet been able to get the latest version of the test app in TestFlight. Like George mentioned in his answer this is probably an issue on Apple's side so I'm afraid all we can do is wait to see if it gets resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

The invitation column for given build number in empty. That means you have not invited any testers to the new build. Open that build and add users. I think you have to add testers for each build. I faced similar problem but when I added testers to new build all my testers got invitation.

Comment: I have added added 4 testers for this build even i tried to remove add them back but no luck . I am not receiving the new update in TestFlight .

Comment: Can you also post the detail view for build 16 ?

Answer (score 0):

Was uploading a few versions successfully to appstore connect for testflight, the new version appears in appstore connect but not on client testflight apps.

Adding ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption in info.plist set to NO and reuploading another version solved the issue for me.